# has_one without belongs_to in ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Imagine I have two schemas: `User` and `Job`, with `Job` being one of `Firefighter`, `Teacher`, `Police Officer`, etc.

Each `User` can only have one `Job` (`has_one`), but each `Job` will have an infinite number of `User`, and I'm really not even concerned with being able to find the `User` from a given `Job`.

I can't figure out has to define a `has_one` on the `User` without *also* including a `belongs_to` on the `Job` and still be able to preload the association. I know I could define this as a `many_to_many` using a `UserClass` table, but that seems like overkill for something this simple. I'm struggling to wrap my head around my options here.

Comment: Sounds like you want `User belongs_to :job` and `Job has_many :users`? or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I think you're absolutely right, and the issue was just me having a mental block against a `User` belonging to a `Job`. For some reason I had it stuck in my mind that the `User` had to be the "owner" of the association.

Answer (score 0):

> Each User can only have one Job (has_one), but each Job will have an infinite number of User, and I'm really not even concerned with being able to find the User from a given Job.

I think this is what you are trying to do. Each User `belongs_to` a job and each Job `has_many` Users.

#### Users:

in migration:

```elixir
def change do
  create table(:users) do
    add :job_id, references(:jobs, on_delete: :nothing)
  end

  create index(:users, [:job_id])
end
```

in model:

```elixir
defmodule User do
  schema "users" do
    belongs_to :job, Job
  end
end
```

#### Jobs:

in model:

```elixir
defmodule Job do
  schema "jobs" do
    has_many :users, User
  end
end
```